# In Haskell, converting a Lambda function into a regular one

Tags: function, haskell, lambda

Here's a snippet of a Haskell program I'm trying to understand:

```
englishToFrench =  [("the", "le"),("savage", "violent"),("work", "travail"),
         ("wild", "sauvage"),("chance", "occasion"),]

data Entry = Entry {word       :: String,
                    definition :: String,
                    length'    :: Int}
             deriving Show

listOfEntries = map (\(x, y) -> Entry x y (length x)) englishToFrench
```

Briefly, the program takes a list of String tuples and turns out a list of Entry objects.

However, I don't like the lambda functions in the `map` and I'd like to create a regular function to replace it.

I attempted this but it is giving me an error that x and y are not in the scope:

```
entryBuilder x y = Entry x y (length x)

entries = map (entryBuilder x y) englishToFrench
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert the lambda function and what the general method is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your `entryBuilder` function has the wrong type. It should be:

```
entryBuilder :: (String, String) -> Entry
entryBuilder (x, y) = Entry x y (length x)
```

while yours has type

```
String -> String -> Entry
```

the type of `map` is

```
map :: (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

since your list type is [(String, String)] you want a function of type

```
(String, String) -> b
```

to pass to `map`.

This is your `entryBuilder` function, so you can just use

```
listOfEntries = map entryBuilder englishToFrench
```

Note that you can use your existing definition of `entryBuilder` using `uncurry`:

```
entryBuilder :: String -> String -> Entry

listOfEntries = map (uncurry entryBuilder) englishToFrench
```

`uncurry` has the type

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

i.e. it converts a curried function in two arguments into a function with a single pair argument. Since your existing `entryBuilder` function has type

```
String -> String -> Entry
```

`uncurry entryBuilder` has type

```
(String, String) -> Entry
```

which is the function type you require to pass to `map`.

Comment: In your type definition of map, are you sure the [a]->[b] should be together in brackets (it's a function itself??)

Comment: @Imray `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` and `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` are the same, the function arrow is right-associative.

Comment: @Imray - I've added an explanation about `uncurry`. As for `map`, I find it helpful to think of it as a function which lifts a 'regular' function over lists (i.e. takes a function from a to b and returns a function from lists of a to lists of b). I find it easier to see `map f` as producing a function between lists rather than a partial application of a function in two arguments.